# Why are tags automatically closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i use `$("#ID").html("<p><div></div><span></p>");` it shows like:

```
<div id="ID">
<p><div></div><span></span></p>

</div>
```

span tag automatically closed. how i put exactly code in that

```
   <div id="ID">
   <p><div></div><span></p>

    </div
```

second question is how to find uppercase tag:
tag like this:

```
<DIV><DIV> <SPAN><SPAN>
```

3rd quection is How to find invalid tags ?like this:

```
 <div id="ID">
   <p><div></div><span></p>

    </div
```

span tag is an invalid tag

Comment: Browsers fix invalid code so it will be basically impossible to know if invalid. Case has no meaning in HTML. <DIV> is same as <div>

Answer (score 0):

HTML is designed for lazy people who don't follow the strict XML standards. As such, it fixes mistakes.

When an outer tag is closed, any open inner tags are also closed.

All tags are standardized to lowercase.

As for your third question, invalid tags are either ignored, or fixed, so there's no way to find them.

See [the HTML4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.1).

Comment: is there any way to find invalid tags in variable or text box ?

Comment: As i said, invalid tags are either ignored (not parsed as elements), or fixed by the browser. I suppose you could try parsing as XML and see where an error is thrown, but this is liable to lots of false positives with other things that are valid in HTML but not XML.